# CMake Error in rosmsg tutorial

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tutorials, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in the tutorial at [CreateMsgAndSrv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_rosmsg) and got stuck at chapter 3.
Running the command

```
$ rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num
```

got me the following

```
Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [unint8] in package [beginner_tutorials] with paths [['/home/aha/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg', '/home/aha/catkin_ws/devel/share/beginner_tutorials/msg']]
```

and searching the web for a solution I stumbled upon a [thread](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?7929-ROS-Beginner-Tutorials-stuck-rosmsg-compile-step) where someone had somewhat the same problem and said that he made a

```
catkin_make install
```

after the changes at the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt which I did not.
But it made sense so I ran the command and then got the following error during the install process

```
CMake Error at /home/aha/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorials-genmsg.cmake:3    (message):                                                                                             Could not find messages which                                                                          '/home/aha/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg/Num.msg' depends on.                                    Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?                                                         Cannot locate message [unint8] in  package [beginner_tutorials] with paths [['/home/aha/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg']]                                                                                    Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:307 (include) beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:71 (generate_messages)
```

But I followed the tutorial as it is written and did not forget to specify/uncomment "generate_messages".
As I am a Newbie, I am kind of lost now and do not really know how to proceed.
Can someone help me out?

System is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the ROS-Version is Kinetic and I added

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

and

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

to my ~/.bashrc.
Hope this sufficient information for the beginning...

EDIT1:
Content of package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The first test package</description>

  <maintainer email="xxx">xxx</maintainer>

  <license>GPLv3</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>


  <export>

  </export>
</package>
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

add_message_files(
 FILES
 Num.msg
)

generate_messages(
 DEPENDENCIES
 std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Content of Num.msg:

```
int64 sum
string first_name
string last_name
unint8 age
uint32 score
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284147/cmake-error-in-rosmsg-tutorial/) by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Welcome!

> I stumbled upon a thread

Can you please update your question with a link to the thread that you're referring to? Also, please update your question with a copy and paste of your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` files and msg definition
using the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button

**Comment by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on 2018-03-01**:
Oh, sure!
Sorry that I didn't think of it before.
Is there an easy way to add parapgraphs without getting the text out of the preformatted text field?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Sorry, I don't understand your question.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Just paste your text into the editor, then highlight anything that should be formatted and click the `101010` button.

**Comment by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on 2018-03-01**:
seems not to work...followed you instructions but nothing happens :/

EDIT: no it worked, my browser did't show it properly to my, sorry again!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Are you sure that you're following my instructions? I just did exactly what they say and it worked.

**Comment by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on 2018-03-01**:
After changing the xml- and txt-file, what did you do then?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
I only removed the comments from your `CMakeLists.txt` to make it fit better and easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there's a typo in your message definition. You have `unint8` instead of `uint8` for the `age` property

```
int64 sum
string first_name
string last_name
unint8 age          # right here
uint32 score
```

It should be

```
int64 sum
string first_name
string last_name
uint8 age
uint32 score
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on 2018-03-01**:
....
god
I'm gonna burrow my self very very very deep
sooo sorry for asking a stupid question and in the end it is a typo....
I mean, it is also clearly visible in the error message -.-
Thank you very much for the quick help!!!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
No worries, we've all been there. Please click on the check mark to mark this answer as correct.